# getting all the inherited classes of a class

Tags: c++

This might, most probably, not possible at all. I want to know if there is a way to get all the classes that inherit from an other. somthing like this:

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
public:
 static string getChildren(); //<- magic function
};

class B: A{};

class C: A{};

void main(){

    cout<< A.getChildren();


}
```

=========================== Output ================================

```
B C
```

Comment: Not possible to do that automatically.

Comment: I would guess: not posible, so grep through the code by `grep -Rn "class [a-zA-Z]\+: A\>"`

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you could probably let the derived classes register themselves in some way with your base class. However, there is no automagic way for this.

Comment: but how they can register before be instanced?

Comment: You register them from elsewhere (e.g. your main, or any other initialization function), since it needs to be done once per derived class.

Comment: You could also call a base class method from the constructor of the derived class -- the base class is guaranteed to be fully instantiated before the body of the derived class' constructor is called.

Comment: Can you describe the problem your having where you think finding the names of all derived classes is the answer? Note that even if you got the names, there isn't anything you can do with them.

Comment: I am making a scripting lenguage for a specific task. I want to create a vector of all the functions (pointer to classes) implemented in the lenguage. The functions are all inherence of one class. I will like to automatize the process of getting this vector and not to need to change several parts of the code (so avoid problems when others change my code). So every time a new class is implemented the vector contian this new class

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. There could be derived classes off in other modules that `getChildren` doesn't necessarily always have access to.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. Take in mind that different modules may inherit from classes you define. It is not possible to keep track of that from within the base class.

Comment: If are all in the same file not even with some compiler command ("#")?